# How work with wsdl service(Azure based) from android application

Tags: java, android, soap, wsdl, ksoap2

1).I generated Web Service Client from WSDL (use Axis2 1.5 carnel, wsdl2java,Tomcat 7.0);

2). Accessing a JAX-WS web service from Android use KSoap2-android library (I tested this lib on service http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertWeight.asmx and it works ok). But work with http://xxx.svc?wsdl I can't connect to the service. When I generated the Web Service Client from Android Progect I get this error : "IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL: java.io.IOException: Emitter failure. There is an undefined binding (BasicHttpBinding_ICustomerService) in the WSDL document. Hint: make sure is fully qualified."

3). From Web Service Client I make service.jar, which used on Android Progect how lib, but not working.

4). When I used ksoap2 I get this error:

[2012-06-26 17:25:33 - TranscribeMe_2.2] Dx 1 error; aborting [2012-06-26 17:25:33 - TranscribeMe_2.2] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 [2012-06-26 17:26:32 - TMP] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class (org.ksoap2.transport.KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE$1) that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is not an inner class. [2012-06-26 17:26:33 - TMP] Dx trouble processing "javax/xml/ws/Dispatch.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform. It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

[2012-06-26 17:26:33 - TMP] Dx 1 error; aborting [2012-06-26 17:26:33 - TMP] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Please, help me...

Answer (score 0):

IF you will search StackOverFlow for Axis and WCF/WSDL issues you will find a lot without any answer or suggestion so there is not a lot you would be able to

About your following error:

```
There is an undefined binding (BasicHttpBinding_ICustomerService) in the WSDL document.
Hint: make sure is fully qualified."
```

I can say that the problem probably related with how you ICustomerService bindings are defined. As you have chosen BasicHttpBinding, please make sure all the parameters are correct . If you check your Axis generated WSDL, you will be able to verify it easily.

Also in some cases you might hit namespace issues and which could cause Axis WSDL to genatate service.svc?wsdl=wsdl0 and service.svc?wsdl=wsdl1. If that is the case, you can resolve namespace issues by adding namespace attribute for your each data contract along with message header, body and added bindingnamespace attribute in web service end point.

My first suggestion will be to create a simple C# client application and connect to your Windows Azure WCF service to and verify you could connect using BasicHttpBindings without any problem and then use Java app to do the same. If you see the problem, compare the network traffic between two to see the different which might help you to figure out the root cause and for very specific problem ask questions at SO and you will get proper help. Good Luck!!